# How can you detect when a site has its own blog?

Tags: support, blog

At the bottom of each Stack Exchange website there is a link called blog. In most (I had thought all) cases it points to a single blog location. I just noticed that Super User and Server Fault now seem to point to their own independent blogs.

How can I see what site has a separate blog, compared to a site that points back to the main blog.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Note that there is also a "blog link" at the *top* of the site now: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y77Fa.png. Right now, this only appears to lower-rep users due to space constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very overt about it, but the simplest way is to simply hover over the `blog` link and see what the destination is.

If it says `http://blog.stackoverflow.com`, then it goes there. If it says something else, like how on [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) it says `http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/`, then it goes somewhere else.

There is no current indication other than this, nor to my knowledge is there a listing of exactly which sites have such blogs or not.

Comment: Listing of sites that have blog: Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange (official/network-wide), Server Fault (official), Super User & Gaming.